# How to delete all lines before the second match of a pattern with sed?

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have the following file:

```
first
second
third
fourth
third
fifth
sixth
```

Using `cat file | sed -n '/third/,$p'` I can print starting from the first match, in order to get:

```
third
fourth
third
fifth
sixth
```

Is it possible to modify the `sed` command such that it essentially ignores the first match and prints from the second match? That would be:

```
third
fifth
sixth
```

Comment: UUOC Award nominee... ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed '1,/third/d' file | sed -n '/third/,$p'
```

Output:

```
third
fifth
sixth
```

Comment: No that won't work if there are more than 2 occurrences of `third` in the file.

Comment: Or may be I misinterpreted requirement. I interpreted it as OP wants to skip all but last match but example had only 2 matches so OP asked to ignore first one.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an `awk` that does that by keeping a buffer to store all lines from occurrence of `third` in a line and resetting the buffer when `third` is found again:

```
awk '/third/{p=$0 RS; next} p{p=p $0 RS} END{printf "%s", p}' file
```

```
third
fifth
sixth
```

Alternatively, you may use this `tac + awk`:

```
tac file | awk '1; /third/{exit}' | tac
```

```
third
fifth
sixth
```

Comment: This prints from the last match, but the question says: *...ignores the first match and prints from the second match?*

Comment: Hmm may be I misinterpreted requirement. I interpreted it as OP wants to skip all but last match but example had only 2 matches so OP asked to ignore first one.

Comment: True, that's possible. But even judging from the title, I believe OP meant literally the 2nd match. Who knows :)

Comment: Agree with you. I will wait for OP's comment then modify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

With gnu sed

```
sed '/third/!d;:A;N;/\nthird/!{s/[^\n]*\n//;bA };s/[^\n]*\n//;:B;N;bB' infile
```

Comment: Excellent. If you want to write to the file immediately, example where I read ALL .conf files: sed -i '/third/!d;:A;N;/\nthird/!{s/[^\n]*\n//;bA };s/[^\n]*\n//;:B;N;bB' *.conf